# Android Bluetooth: ArrayAdapter doesnt fill . (Spinner)

Tags: android, bluetooth, spinner

This code doesnt work, It should appear all devices in spinner. I Include Manifest code , mRecieve and Oncreate.

My Manifest Code:

```
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />`
```

My mReceiver:

```
`private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            String deviceName = device.getName();
            String deviceHardwareAddress = device.getAddress();
            spinnerArrayAdapter.add(deviceName+ "\n"+deviceHardwareAddress);
            spinnerArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }`
```

My On Create :

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    spinner_bluetooth_list = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    txt_password = findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
    txt_mac_address = findViewById(R.id.txt_mac_address);
    spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(SettingsActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    spinner_bluetooth_list.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);


}
```

Comment: Please share more source code.

Comment: It would be much easier to understand what's going on if your code was properly formatted

Comment: yes i have. . and i call startdiscovery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not get what you're trying to do

Firstly be sure that you sent **IntentFilter** to this **BroadCast**

if you do not this **snippet** will help you

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);
```

if the first step is done then be sure you have already started the discovery

```
mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
```

and do not forget when you finished (to not get involved in performance issues)

```
mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
```

Ensure declaring all **permission**s that required for what you want .

if the previous steps did not solve your problem please describe your problem in more details because your problem is blurred.

Comment: listen to me you did not start Discovery try using 
mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

Comment: do you have an facebook account ? if you want i have a group in Facebook for only android developers in java and there are a lot of professionals

Comment: yes i have facebook. and i start Discovery and it still doesnt work.

Comment: Okay post the whole code of this activity. try next time to share more detailed problem.

Comment: This is my Facebook account add me: m7madamerx0@yahoo.com

Comment: post the whole code now and i'll try to add you in my android group. good luck

Comment: cant see your account. can i know your fb,com/username

Comment: Thank you . I forgot the startdiscovery() part :)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you invoke `notifyDataSetChanged()` for `Adapter`?

```
private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            spinnerArrayAdapter.add(bluetoothDevice.getName() + "\n"
                    + bluetoothDevice.getAddress());
            spinnerArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() //OVER HERE!
        }
    }
};
```